# PLS-00201: identifier 'TYR' must be declared

Tags: sql, cursor

I'm having a problem when trying to populate two tables with one cursor. It's the Term table and the time table. below is the code. Any help would really appreciated. Thanks

PS: I have created create sequence dw_time_seq; and create sequence dw_term_seq;

```
declare
  Cursor c_term is

  select temprequestid, termdate, status, tempid, tempcoverid
    from term;

begin
  for c_rec in c_term loop

    insert into dw_term values(
      dw_term_seq.nextval,
      c_rec.temprequestid,
      c_rec.termdate,
      c_rec.status,
      c_rec.tempid,
      c_rec.tempcoverid
    );

    insert into dw_time values(
      dw_time_seq.nextval,
      c_rec.tdate,
      c_rec.tweek,
      c_rec.tmonth,
      c_rec.tyear
    );
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: So.... what problem do you have exactly?

Comment: I get the error msg PLS-00201: identifier 'TYEAR' must be declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the error is `PLS-00201: identifier 'TYEAR' must be declared`, remove the `c_rec.` part of `c_rec.tyear`. `tyear` is a local variable, not a field in the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Proably, the error you get is - *in contradiction to the post's title* - `PLS-00201: identifier 'TYEAR' must be declared`. This is because the variable `tyear` hadn't been declared. Declare it like so

```
 declare
   tyear number;

   cursor c_term is ...
```

Also, the part reading `c_rec.tyear` should then of course just be this variable `tyear` instead.